# JS If Statements and Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, if-statement, radio-button

I have a very simple form in which I want the user to be able to answer each question, and if an answer has a sub-question, the sub-question will show when the appropriate answer is checked..and I am failing at getting this to work...

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".sub-question").hide();

            var yes = document.getElementById("#Q4A1");


            if(yes.checked){
                    $(".sub-question").show(200);
            }
    });
    </script>
```

Currently I'm getting a "null" reference error for my `yes.checked` condition.

```
<div class="question-content">
<span>Example text example text</span>
<form id="question-04">
<label><input type="radio" name="question-04" value="yes"  id="Q4A1"> Yes</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="question-04" value="no"> No</label>
</form>
<div class="sub-question">
<div class="sub-question-content">
<span>Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque facilisis non mauris non malesuada. Duis in accumsan metus. Ut eget nulla neque?</span>
<form id="subquestion-04">
<label><input type="radio" name="question-04" value="yes"> Yes</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="question-04" value="no"> No</label>
</form>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

All I want to do is show the "sub-question" if the answer is yes. I'd rather not explicitly refer to the input element, if possible and instead refer to the form element, just in case "no" has sub-questions. I want to make this as dynamic as possible. Thank for any help!

Comment: `var yes = document.getElementById("#Q4A1");` should be `var yes = document.getElementById("Q4A1");`

Comment: I think you'd be far better off using only one form to contain all questions, and `fieldsets` to contain questions, with nested `fieldsets` to contain sub-questions.

Comment: I'm not so sure by what you meant by "not explicitly refer to the input element" but here is something I did http://jsfiddle.net/ST4C5/1/

Comment: sorry this one http://jsfiddle.net/ST4C5/2/

Comment: @user2786485 can you please accept the answer if it is good enough for you?

Comment: @JeremyD you mean user1873857 :)

Comment: @user2786485 Yes right, but you can upvote if you want to ahha.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ST4C5/)

You need to listen to the change event on the button radio.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".sub-question").hide();
        $("#Q4A1").change(function () {
             $(".sub-question").show(200);
        });
});
```

Of course you might have to modify it to fit your need but you got the idea.
You can just use javascript to listen to the change event on the radio button, and show you sub question when needed.

It is easy to extend it if you wanna do the same with the 'no' answer, but I let you do that, this is why programming is fun.